# hex literal too big in sqlite

Tags: mysql, django, sqlite

So I wanted to convert msyql query to sqlite where in it has images in hex code,when I run the same query in sqlite browser  it is giving me an error, what is the correct way of doing it.

```
Result: hex literal too big: 0x73616666726f6e2e6a7067
At line 1:
INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `yeild`, `image`, `city`, `info`, `fertilizer`) VALUES
(9, 'Wheat', 0x77686561742e6a7067, 'Bangalore', 'Weather that is comfortable for humans is also good for wheat. Wheat needs 12\r\nto 15 inches (31 to 38 centimetres) of water to produce a')


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `test` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  `yeild` varchar(40) NOT NULL,
  `image` blob NOT NULL,
  `city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `info` varchar(60000) NOT NULL,
  `fertilizer` varchar(5000) NOT NULL);
```

Comment: Can you please share DDL of table.  What is datatype of `image`  field

Comment: i have used blob data type

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to insert a blob literal, not a number:

```
X'77686561742e6a7067'
```

From [the documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_expr.html):

> Hexadecimal integer literals are interpreted as 64-bit two's-complement integers and are thus limited to sixteen significant digits of precision.

and

> BLOB literals are string literals containing hexadecimal data and preceded by a single "x" or "X" character. Example: X'53514C697465'

Answer (score 1):

```
 INSERT INTO `test` (`id`, `yeild`, `image`, `city`, `info`, `fertilizer`) VALUES
(9, 'Wheat', '0x77686561742e6a7067', 'Bangalore', 'Weather that is comfortable for humans is also good for wheat. Wheat needs 12\r\nto 15 inches (31 to 38 centimetres) of water to produce a', 'My fertilizser');
```

Your hex value should be in quotes. 
Also, you are passing only 5 input values but the table have 6 fields.

[Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/fa3e4/1)

Comment: This doesn't do as intended - `select typeof(image) from test` shows that it's being stored as text, because sqlite's typing is very flexible.