# Update large blob in SQLite

Tags: database, sqlite

An application in my computer uses SQLite to store its settings, but the database is poorly designed - it stores nearly all data(JSON format, more than 4MB) just in one blob.
Now I need to update a small piece of this blob to fix a bug, but when I try to execute UPDATE operation, **SQLite will throw an error: hex literal too big**.
The error is quite understandable, 4MB is indeed ***too big*** for a single blob as literal.
So, is there any other approach to update this "massive" blob? SQL has proved incompetent for this job.
By the way, the application is Logitech GHUB, it used to store its settings simply in a JSON file. I have no idea why the developer team migrates to database in such a weird way.

Comment: Another [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60689924/hex-literal-too-big-in-sqlite) discusses the same topic. Does that help you ? Limit of BLOB is 2GB, so it should be possible.

Comment: Without a [mre], we can only guess, but you should be using a blob literal for a blob (`X'1234ABCD'`), not a hex literal (`0x1234ABCD`).  Or better yet, a bound parameter.

Comment: @AnonCoward Thanks for your comments. This is exactly my problem! I'm using HeidiSQL to manage the database, and I've just looked into its SQL log, it indeed converted the text into hex literal and cause this problem. Now I've reported this bug to HeidiSQL's forum, hoping it could get fixed soon.