# Migrate field BLOB in table mysql to field BLOB in table sqlite

Tags: mysql, sqlite, blob

I have a table containing one column BLOB type in database mysql. I want export to sqlite database with similar structure, but in sqlite database the destination table throws error for too long bytes

This column BLOB in database mysql belongs to images

I need help, please

Comment: Do you have the option of truncating the source BLOB to the limit of sqlite BLOB size maximum?

Comment: Rather than truncation,, could the BLOB become LBLOB and RBLOB with split images and there would be NO image loss.

Comment: how can change sqlite BLOB size maximum?

Comment: You are not likely able to change sqlite BLOB max size.  Limited by their design, most likely.  Will dig around for you in sqlite documentation.

Comment: Here is the URL for sqlite limits.  It may help you.  https://www.sqlite.org/limits.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks, I found the answer I was looking for.

[hex literal too big in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60689924/hex-literal-too-big-in-sqlite)

I really appreciate the help